# Java Robot .keypress doesn't work on a Virtual Machine running Windows 10

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine, keypress, keyrelease

I can't seem to make the Robot .keypress/keyrelease methods from Java to work inside a Virtual Machine when I'm not connected to that virtual machine.
It works as expected when I'm connected to the VM using the remote connection from my station.
The idea is I want to be able to use send a sequence of keys that represent a path e.g. C://myfile.txt inside a window upload frame like the following picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGysA.png)

I have the following code

```
public class Keyboard {

private Robot robot;


public Keyboard() throws AWTException {
    this.robot = new Robot();
}


public void type(CharSequence characters) {
    int length = characters.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char character = characters.charAt(i);
        type(character);
    }
}

public void type(char character) {
    switch (character) {
        case 'a': doType(VK_A); break;
        case 'b': doType(VK_B); break;
        case 'c': doType(VK_C); break;
        case 'd': doType(VK_D); break;
        case 'e': doType(VK_E); break;
        case 'f': doType(VK_F); break;
        case 'g': doType(VK_G); break;
        case 'h': doType(VK_H); break;
        case 'i': doType(VK_I); break;
        case 'j': doType(VK_J); break;
        case 'k': doType(VK_K); break;
        case 'l': doType(VK_L); break;
        case 'm': doType(VK_M); break;
        case 'n': doType(VK_N); break;
        case 'o': doType(VK_O); break;
        case 'p': doType(VK_P); break;
        case 'q': doType(VK_Q); break;
        case 'r': doType(VK_R); break;
        case 's': doType(VK_S); break;
        case 't': doType(VK_T); break;
        case 'u': doType(VK_U); break;
        case 'v': doType(VK_V); break;
        case 'w': doType(VK_W); break;
        case 'x': doType(VK_X); break;
        case 'y': doType(VK_Y); break;
        case 'z': doType(VK_Z); break;
        case 'A': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_A); break;
        case 'B': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_B); break;
        case 'C': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_C); break;
        case 'D': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_D); break;
        case 'E': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_E); break;
        case 'F': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_F); break;
        case 'G': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_G); break;
        case 'H': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_H); break;
        case 'I': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_I); break;
        case 'J': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_J); break;
        case 'K': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_K); break;
        case 'L': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_L); break;
        case 'M': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_M); break;
        case 'N': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_N); break;
        case 'O': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_O); break;
        case 'P': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_P); break;
        case 'Q': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Q); break;
        case 'R': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_R); break;
        case 'S': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_S); break;
        case 'T': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_T); break;
        case 'U': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_U); break;
        case 'V': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_V); break;
        case 'W': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_W); break;
        case 'X': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_X); break;
        case 'Y': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Y); break;
        case 'Z': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Z); break;
        case '`': doType(VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '0': doType(VK_0); break;
        case '1': doType(VK_1); break;
        case '2': doType(VK_2); break;
        case '3': doType(VK_3); break;
        case '4': doType(VK_4); break;
        case '5': doType(VK_5); break;
        case '6': doType(VK_6); break;
        case '7': doType(VK_7); break;
        case '8': doType(VK_8); break;
        case '9': doType(VK_9); break;
        case '-': doType(VK_MINUS); break;
        case '=': doType(VK_EQUALS); break;
        case '~': doType(VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '!': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK); break;
        case '@': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_AT); break;
        case '#': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_NUMBER_SIGN); break;
        case '$': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_DOLLAR); break;
        case '%': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_5); break;
        case '^': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_CIRCUMFLEX); break;
        case '&': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_AMPERSAND); break;
        case '*': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_ASTERISK); break;
        case '(': doType(VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case ')': doType(VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case '_': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_UNDERSCORE); break;
        case '+': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_PLUS); break;
        case '\t': doType(VK_TAB); break;
        case '\n': doType(VK_ENTER); break;
        case '[': doType(VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case ']': doType(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '\\': doType(VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case '{': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case '}': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '|': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case ';': doType(VK_SEMICOLON); break;
        case ':': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_SEMICOLON); break;
        case '\'': doType(VK_QUOTE); break;
        case '"': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_QUOTEDBL); break;
        case ',': doType(VK_COMMA); break;
        case '<': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_COMMA); break;
        case '.': doType(VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '>': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '/': doType(VK_SLASH); break;
        case '?': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_SLASH); break;
        case ' ': doType(VK_SPACE); break;
        case '\b': doType(VK_BACK_SPACE); break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
    }
}

private void doType(int... keyCodes) {
    doType(keyCodes, 0, keyCodes.length);
}

private void doType(int[] keyCodes, int offset, int length) {
    if (length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    robot.keyPress(keyCodes[offset]);
    doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
    robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
}
```

}

And the way i use this is:

```
 Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
 keyboard.type(path);
```

Comment: I bet that there is no desktop to work with when no remote session is established

Comment: Could be it, it's strange that the package is running on the VM via a windows task scheduler, this should work.